# how do i solve error: unable to run mksdcard sdk tool . in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-sdk-tools

I'm using VPN and I installed Android Studio, but now I'm failing to install Android SDK. If I'm launching it, I'm getting a message `unable to run mksdcard sdk tool` with tips that some libraries may be missing. 
How would I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` (could be different in your case) and search for `mksdcard.exe` - try to run It and see If you can run It - in my case I was getting error that I am missing `MSVCP140.dll` - you need to install Visual C++ runtimes - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/vcruntime140dll-and-msvcp140dll-missing-in-windows/220f1caf-8eb9-413d-a7fe-1b13df1bfa5d